# .click() method is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here i have a link of class name "lineIcon" for that i written 2 functions, 
1st one is as follows,- iam adding a class 'overlayShow'. 
now on clicking on 'overlayshow' iam adding one more class called "overlayHide" and removing existing class 'overlayshow'. adding class and removing class are by using .addClass() and .removeClass() methods. so till now code is wokring as i intended.

2nd function which as follows, on clicking "overlayHide" iam adding previous class 'overlayshow' and removing "overlayHide" class.

now issue is with 2nd function is not firing even not giving the alert but in 1st function class is removed and added 'overlayHide' class.

```
$('.lineIcon').addClass('overlayShow');
$('.overlayShow').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('overlayHide');
    $(this).removeClass('overlayShow');
})

$('.overlayHide').click(function () {
    alert("fsdf");
    $(this).addClass('overlayShow');
    $(this).removeClass('overlayHide');
})
```

Comment: yes on jquery mobile

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/ might help!

Comment: All that could be replaced with one line in a click function: `$('.lineIcon').toggleClass('overlayShow overlayHide');`

Comment: can't you do this with one click handler and just toggle the 2 classes: $('.lineIcon').toggleClass('overlayShow').toggleClass('overlayHide');

Comment: `$('.overlayHide').click` does *not* mean "on clicking overlayHide". It means "on clicking any element that had class overlayHide at the point in time when that statement ran"

Comment: $('.lineIcon').toggleClass('overlayShow').toggleClass('overlayHide'); by add this in both events class names are changing but everytime when we click 1st event is firing but not 2nd

Comment: @Ninsly- when we click on it class names toggle between 'overlayShow' and 'overlayHide' but 2nd event is not fired

Comment: You just need one click handler: $('.lineIcon').on("click", function(){ $(this).toggleClass('overlayShow').toggleClass('overlayHide'); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that when you declare a selector `$('selector')` it is only creating a static list of elements that currently match the selectors criteria, therefore, it is not a live list of elements that match `$('.overlayShow')` or `$('.overlayHide')`

Using [`jQuery.fn.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can declare your event and then a selector to filter  descendants of the selected elements that will call the handler.

This should solve your issue:

```js
$('.lineIcon').addClass('overlayShow');

$(document)
  .on( 'click' , '.overlayShow' , function(){
    $(this).addClass('overlayHide');
    $(this).removeClass('overlayShow');
  })
  .on( 'click' , '.overlayHide' , function(){
    $(this).addClass('overlayShow');
    $(this).removeClass('overlayHide');
  });
```

Here is a live example of the code I provided

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/70oebfu3/)

### Update:

As [@ezanker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046313/click-method-is-not-working/27047683#comment42618484_27047683) stated, having two functions for one handler is unnecessary and can be done in a single function.

He also provide a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/70oebfu3/2/).

### Reference:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/70oebfu3/)
- [`@ezanker's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046313/click-method-is-not-working/27047683#comment42618484_27047683)
- [`@ezanker's jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/70oebfu3/2/)

Comment: You are correct that event delegation will work, however, there is no need to add 2 click event handlers to the same DOM element just to toggle classes.  This can be done with a single handler: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/70oebfu3/2/

Comment: @ezanker +1 This is true. Giving him an alternate version of his code that looked similar is what I was trying to do. In terms of performance, your example is quicker, more efficient and I would recommend it. I updated my post crediting your comment.